# Android SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder is not working while getting data from XML Parsing

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

My code as follows:

```
     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    String xml = ParseXMLMethods.getXML();
    Document doc = ParseXMLMethods.XMLfromString(xml);

    NodeList children = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

    for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) 
    {                           
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
        Element e = (Element)children.item(i);



        map.put("PID", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put("Passionname", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put("Progress", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e,KEY_PROGRESS));
        Log.d("Progress",ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e,KEY_PROGRESS));
        map.put("Duedate", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, KEY_DUEDATE));
        map.put("Action", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, KEY_ACTION));

        mylist.add(map);
    }

    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), mylist , R.layout.row, 
            new String[] { KEY_TITLE,KEY_PROGRESS,KEY_DUEDATE,KEY_ACTION}, 
            new int[] {R.id.txt,R.id.progress, R.id.FROM_CELL, R.id.del_btn})
    {

       @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
       {

              return itemView;
        }
    };

   adapter.setViewBinder(new MyBinder());
   list.setAdapter(adapter);
   list.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```

My ViewBinder class as follows:

```
    class MyBinder implements ViewBinder{
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation) {
        if(view.getId() == R.id.progress){
            String stringval = (String) data;
            int progressValue = Integer.parseInt(stringval);
            ProgressBar progressbar = (ProgressBar) view;
            progressbar.setProgress(progressValue);

            Resources res = getResources();
            Rect bounds = progressbar.getProgressDrawable().getBounds();

            if(progressValue==100)
            {
                progressbar.setProgressDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.red_progressbar));
            }
            else
            {
                progressbar.setProgressDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.green_progreesbar));
            }
            progressbar.getProgressDrawable().setBounds(bounds);


            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

whenever run above code got the below errors:

12-01 04:55:37.162: E/AndroidRuntime(3478): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "50 "
12-01 04:55:37.162: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
12-01 04:55:37.162: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)

but this code run successfully while using a static array for my Progress bar.Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Here problem is in the data of XML file given below
Invalid int: "50 ".Here a space exists after 50 in my xml file,That's why I am getting error.I wasted 3 hr for this issue.